# VBA excel Overload another add-in function

Tags: excel, overloading, vba

Question!
I have an add-in we created at work, say foo.xla, and it has a function foo_sub(arg1).

Now, I want to improve the way that foo_sub(arg1) behaves but withour editting the original add-in code, since as soon as they update it, I must migrate my code from the old add-in to the newer.

Is there a way I could write foo_sub(arg1) in a different add-in, say fee.xla, so that every time I call foo_sub from a worksheet the one that get's called is the one I wrote?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a lot of similar issues when trying to [overload a constructor in VBA in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731052/is-there-a-way-to-overload-the-constructor-initialize-procedure-for-a-class-in).

However, I think your problem is a little different.  You're not necessarily trying to overload the function by providing a separate method with the same name and different parameters; you're trying to add a method with the exact same name, return type, and parameters and figure out a way to have Excel call your function rather than that of the add-in.

I'm not positive, but I don't think this is possible in Excel VBA.  If you try to call a function that's defined in multiple places, it will get confused and tell you that it doesn't know which one to call.

You might create a wrapper function called `my_foo_sub(arg1)` which has custom code in it.  Then, if you need to switch to the new `foo_sub(arg1)` when the `.xla` file is updated, you could just comment out your custom code and add a call to `foo_sub(arg1)`.  This is far from ideal, but it might help.

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid that you and I are right. Excel can't handle it this way sice there is no something like a hyerarchy of who is parent of who then to prioritize calls since I am not using objects to create this functionality. 

I can't create wrapper functions since other people here at work may need to have my very own add-in to re-open the file and get the same results in which case I'd better choose to just pass my add-in around or improve the current one that everyone has! :/ hehe

Thanks on taking a time to understand what my problem is.

Answer (score 0):

This may help: [Function Overloading and UDF in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64436/function-overloading-in-excel-vba)