# VBA for Office Class Module (Object) Factory

Tags: ms-access, vba, inheritance, abstract-class, factory

I have a relatively complex application for Access 2007 written in VBA (4 enumerations, 7 modules, 38 class-modules, 86 forms, and a whole slew of tables and queries) .  I've found a situation where it would be beneficial to use an Object Factory design, but so far I am unable to find a clean way to implement this type of functionality without the standard abstract/inheritance that is easily accomplished in VB or C#.

Has anyone had any experience implementing a factory design in VBA, and is it even possible? ... Or is there a neat "trick" that can help me obtain the same overall goal?

My experience on factory design is limited to C#, and i've never done it in VB, so maybe there is something in VBA that is common to VB that I am missing.

**Example**

I will be receiving a specific date.  based on that date i will need to calculate anywhere between 2 and 5 other dates.  the rules for calculating these dates changes based on the "type" of date being entered.

So if I have a date of 07/15/2009, and this is a type 1 date it would return

07/15/2010 for date 1, 07/15/2011 for date 2, 07/15/2012 for date 3, 06/10/2012 for date 4 and 07/10/2012 for date 5

if i put the same date but put it in as a date type 2 i would get
null for date 1, null for date 2, null for date 3, 06/10/2011 for date 4 and 07/10/2011 for date 5

so for each set of rules there will be a minimum of 3 possible max of 6 (for now this could always expand at any time) i will basically be entering a starting date... the rule... and returning an object that will contain all of the date properties.

I hope that helps a little bit.

Comment: Wow ! Access 2008 ! Where did you find THAT ? A see sharp special ?

Comment: /facepalm my mistake.  2007.  At least in my defense the 7 and 8 are right beside each other on the keyboard ><

Comment: These aren't really "factory"-specific answers, but you might find them helpful re: inheritance and object creation in VBA. In short, it's a pain. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669270/vba-inheritance-analog-of-super/3671434#3671434 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731052/is-there-a-way-to-overload-the-constructor-initialize-procedure-for-a-class-in/1744818#1744818

Comment: I think you'd likely get better answers with a less abstract question. We know VBA can't do exactly what you're asking for in the general case, but if you'd describe a specific task where you'd like to apply the "factory" approach, perhaps old Access hands can give you advice on how to code it up more efficiently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've probably missed the point of the question, but why not have a "factory" method / "constructor" in a standard module:

```
'default constructor
    Public Function MyClassFactory() As MyClass
        Set MyClassFactory = New MyClass
    End Function
```

Or, if you need a "constructor" with parameters:

```
'Constructor with parameters
    Public Function MyClassFactory(Param1 As ParamObject1, Param2 As ParamObject2) As MyClass
        Dim MyThing As MyClass
        Set MyThing = New MyClass

    'MyObjectInitializer is a Sub that does what a constructor should do
        MyThing.MyObjectInitializer Param1, Param2
        Set MyClassFactory = MyThing
    End Function
```

Etc, etc.

If you ALWAYS create MyObject instances using this, then this "Factory Pattern" replaces the constructor.

You can modify this code to only create singletons, etc.  Sometimes, VBA's downsides (eg, standard modules having global scope) can be turned into something useful.

To call it you just do:

```
Dim Thing As MyClass
Set Thing = MyClassFactory(Param1, Param2)
```

With this kind of thing you are pretty close to having a constructor... or a Factory...

I must be missing something.  My understanding of the Factory pattern is probably too simplistic, but then you probably don't want to get too complex in VBA.  If you find you need to, there is probably a design issue.

Comment: That's how I do it. I IS Painful not having a real constructor . . .

Comment: Sorry, I've just now gotten the time to get back to this project... yes, i see where you are coming from and it does make sense... but the factory will have to be able to actually return different objects... like i would have a base "abstract" class, and 4 - 6 classes that inherit that class. the factory would decide which of the inheriting classes to return based on the information given to it...

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way to implement a Factory Pattern in VBA that is described very well on the Rubberduck website https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2016/07/05/oop-vba-pt-2-factories-and-cheap-hotels/. 
Here is my attempt to explain it. I know there is probably a more concise way to do this but I am trying to demonstrate two things: the use of a factory pattern and dependency injection to construct objects without having to New them up; and the ability to use polymorphism in VBA, so that there can be multiple different implementations of an abstract interface class.
Open to feedback. Here goes:

1. Create a simple Interface class called IExampleClass and set the following members on it:

> ```
> Option Explicit
>
> Public Property Get Firstname() As String
> End Property
>
> Public Property Get Lastname() As String
> End Property
>
> Public Function ToString() As String
> End Function
> ```

2. Create an implementation class, ExampleClass. Note this has a Create method. This is your factory method. Also notice the Self getter, which allows the Create method to use a really neat syntax:

> ```
> Option Explicit     
> Private Type TExample
>     Firstname As String
>     Lastname As String
> End Type
>
> Private this As TExample
>
> Implements IExampleClass
>
> Public Property Get Firstname() As String
>     FirstName = this.Firstname
> End Property
>
> Public Property Let Firstname(Value As String)
>     this.Firstname = Value
> End Property
>
> Public Property Get Lastname() As String
>     Lastname = this.Lastname
> End Property
>
> Public Property Let Lastname(Value As String)
>     this.Lastname = Value
> End Property
>
> Public Property Get Self() As IExampleClass
>     Set Self = Me
> End Property
>
> Public Function Create(ByVal First As String, ByVal Last As String)
>     With New ExampleClass
>         this.Firstname = First
>         this.Lastname = Last
>         Set Create = Self
>     End With
> End Function
>
> Private Property Get IExampleClass_Firstname() As String
>     IExampleClass_Firstname = this.Firstname
> End Property
>
> Private Property Get IExampleClass_Lastname() As String
>     IExampleClass_Lastname = this.Lastname
> End Property
>
> Private Function IExampleClass_ToString() As String
>     IExampleClass_ToString = this.Firstname & " " & this.Lastname
> End Function
> ```

Note how in this class the implementation of each of the members in the Interface has a private signature, so code that consumes this ExampleClass can only access the ToString method from the IExampleClass interface (abstract) object.

3. Now lets Create another class which implements the IExampleClass interface, calling it BackwardsExampleClass:

> ```
>    Option Explicit
>    Private Type TExample
>        Firstname As String
>        Lastname As String
>    End Type
>
>    Private this As TExample
>
>    Implements IExampleClass
>
>    Public Property Get Firstname() As String
>        Firstname = this.Firstname
>    End Property
>
>    Public Property Let Firstname(Value As String)
>        this.Firstname = Value
>    End Property
>
>    Public Property Get Lastname() As String
>        Lastname = this.Lastname
>    End Property
>
>    Public Property Let Lastname(Value As String)
>        this.Lastname = Value
>    End Property
>
>    Public Property Get Self() As IExampleClass
>        Set Self = Me
>    End Property
>
>    Public Function Create(ByVal First As String, ByVal Last As String)
>        With New ExampleClass
>            this.Firstname = First
>            this.Lastname = Last
>            Set Create = Self
>        End With
>    End Function
>
>    Private Property Get IBackwardsExampleClass_Firstname() As String
>        IExampleClass_Firstname = this.Firstname
>    End Property
>
>    Private Property Get IBackwardsExampleClass_Lastname() As String
>        IExampleClass_Lastname = this.Lastname
>    End Property
>
>    Private Function IBackwardsExampleClass_ToString() As String
>       IExampleClass_ToString = this.Lastname & ", " & this.Firstname
>    End Function
> ```

4. Here is the trick to make this Factory Class work, so that yo do not need to use the New Keyword to use the factory, and so you can use Dependency Injection. This is the trick which allows you to set the Factory as a Singleton.
   Now... you need to Remove ExampleClass and BackwardsExampleClass from your project, export it into a folder, open each .cls file in a text editor, set the Predeclared Attribute to "True", save each .cls file, and re-import both class files into your project. What this does is create a default instance of both of these "Factory" classes that implement the IExampleClass interface.
5. Now Type into the immediate pane:

   > ```
   >    Debug.print ExampleClass.Create("John","Smith").ToString
   > ```
   >
   > and it will return the output "John Smith"
6. Next Type into the immediate pane:

   > ```
   >    Debug.print BackwardsExampleClass.Create("John","Smith").ToString
   > ```
   >
   > and it will return the output "Smith, John"

Comment: LOL thanks.  I don't even work for the company that I had that project with anymore, much less do anything in VBA.  Hopefully if someone in the future wonders across this question, your answer might add perspective to what they are looking to do.

Comment: Pleasure, this is my first attempt to answer a question on SE. Hope it makes sense to someone in the future. Cheers.

Comment: Your code is not really initializing new instances of ExampleClass and BackwardsExampleClass correctly, it simply reuses the predeclared instances. If you check the article you are referencing, the Create method needs to set properties of New ExampleClass inside the With block, while you are setting properties of the existing predeclared instance.