# VBA - Trying to understand how to call Class Modules

Tags: excel, vba

I'm learning VBA through Google, YouTube, etc.. and I came across Class Modules.

I have a `Tracker Template`.
Every few days I get a report sent to me (`"Ice cream FG Inv.xlsm"`)

While trying to understand `Class Modules`, I found a template that created a Class Module (within the Tracker Template) `WBIceCreamFGINVxlsm` creating a CodeName for all of the worksheets within the `Ice Cream FG Inv.xlsm Workbook`.

Example:

```
Public Property Get wsinventory() As Worksheet
    Set wsinventory = Workbook.Worksheets("Inventory")
End Property
```

In my module, I want to reference `wsinventory`, but not understanding exactly how to 'call' the Class Module..

Both Workbooks are Open.

I tried to start with:

```
Dim Data As Variant
    Data = wsinventory.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value   (**Variable not Defined**)
```

Then I tried:

```
Dim wsinventory As Worksheets
With wsinventory
    Dim Data As Variant
        Data = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value (**Object variable or With variable not set**)
End With
```

Do I still need to use:

```
Dim DataSource As Workbook
Set DataSource = Workbooks("Ice Cream FG Inv.xlsm")
    With DataSource.Worksheets("Inventory")
    End With
```

If so, what would be the reasoning for using Class Modules?

Comment: Seems like you're over-complicating.

Comment: I very well could be!  I'm googling VBA like crazy trying to find the best / efficient way to do things.. so, when would be a time to use Class Modules.

Comment: Not this occasion... I'd focus on learning the Excel object model first.

Comment: Related or duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1740020/13813219

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a class object before you can access the properties of that class.

Assuming you have this Class and naming it `TestClass`:

```
Private pwsinventory As Worksheet

Public Sub init()
    Set pwsinventory = Worksheets("Inventory")
End Sub

Public Property Set wsinventory(lwsinventory As Worksheet)
    Set pwsinventory = lwsinventory
End Property

Public Property Get wsinventory() As Worksheet
    Set wsinventory = pwsinventory
End Property
```

You can set / get the properties like so:

```
Sub test()
    Dim datacls As TestClass
    Dim data As Worksheet
    
    Set datacls = New TestClass
    Set datacls.wsinventory = Worksheets("inventory")
    Set data = datacls.wsinventory
    
    Debug.Print data.Name
End Sub
```

This, however, is kind of weird and when you have a property you don't want to set (you need to pass an argument) you should use an initiate function. Unfortunately there is no way I know of to do this without manually calling that sub after the class object is created.

```
Sub Test2()
    Dim datacls As TestClass
    
    Set datacls = New TestClass
    
    datacls.init
    
    Debug.Print datacls.wsinventory.Name
End Sub
```

The most common case I use classes for is better containers. Generally storing many of the same class type inside an array / dictionary so it is clear what I'm calling, especially if I need to modify the data in the same manner for each instance.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to give another example. Create a class definition and name it `ArrayData`, and define multiple initialization subroutines

### ArrayData.cls

```
Private m_data() As Variant

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
        
End Sub

Public Sub IntializeEmpty(ByVal rows As Long, ByVal columns As Long)
    ReDim m_data(1 To count, 1 To columns)
End Sub

Public Sub InitializeFromRange(ByRef target As Range)
    If target.rows.count > 1 Or target.columns.count > 1 Then
        m_data = target.Value2
    Else
        ReDim m_data(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        m_data(1, 1) = target.Value
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub InitializeFromArray(ByRef data() As Variant)
    m_data = data
End Sub

Public Property Get RowCount() As Long
    RowCount = UBound(m_data, 1) - LBound(m_data, 1) + 1
End Property

Public Property Get ColCount() As Long
    ColCount = UBound(m_data, 2) - LBound(m_data, 2) + 1
End Property

Public Property Get Item(ByVal row As Long, ByVal col As Long) As Variant
    Item = m_data(row, col)
End Property
Public Property Let Item(ByVal row As Long, ByVal col As Long, ByVal x As Variant)
    m_data(row, col) = x
End Property
```

### Module

To test the code in a code module initialize the class with the `New` keyword and then call one of the custom initialization subroutines.

```
Public Sub TestArray()

    Dim arr As New ArrayData
    arr.InitializeFromRange Sheet1.Range("A2").Resize(10, 1)
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To arr.RowCount
        Debug.Print arr.Item(i, 1)
    Next i

End Sub
```

PS. Also read [this article](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DefaultMember.aspx) on how to designate one property as the default. In the example above if `Item` was the default property then you could write code such as

```
Debug.Print arr(5,2)
```

instead of

```
Debug.Pring arr.Item(5,2)
```